# ROS2 cross compile for ARM: Native method

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, ros2

First of all I found a comparable question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/411572/how-to-cross-compile-ros2-package-for-arm-using-native-method/), but without any answer.

I want to build a ROS package (ros2, foxy) for an arm device. On arm, `colcon build` works well, but takes huge amount of time as the device is low on cpu and memory.

On the page of [cross-compilation tool](https://github.com/ros-tooling/cross_compile), a deprecated message is shown:

**Quote** (highlight by myself)

> It is recommended to use a **native cross-compilation method**, which can
> be up to 8 times faster. See details in this ROS Discourse discussion:
> https://discourse.ros.org/t/call-for-help-maintainership-of-the-ros-cross-compile-tool/26511

I tried to find native-cross compilation [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Cross-compilation.html).

This page mentions again the cross compilation tool, which is marked as deprecated.

I've had a look on the discourse discussion above, but didn't find a good starting point for less experienced one.

**My Task**

I've a ros2 package (c++) which I want to build within ubuntu for usage on arm. The expected result is a folder which contains everything to be copied to target and executed there.

I've managed to do so by means of deprecated cross-compilation tool. Most importantly, it's very slow and does not really help me to avoid long compilation times on target.
Therefore, I'm interested in the way which is marked as "up to 8 times faster"

Where to start?

Comment: have you tried compiling this code inside a docker image meant for cross compilation like in [xdaco repo](https://github.com/xdaco/aarch64-ubuntu-ros-docker)?

Comment: No, I was expecting a `native` workflow which accepts some parameter for `colcon` and then simply provides an install folder for my target device.